How can I remove special character with number from a String in android Java?
I have a String like this:
1984 (as Word$55), 1984-1993 (as Something$74435), 1994-present (as Anything$9324879)
I want to remove the special character $ and the number afterwards so for the final result be
1984 (as Word), 1984-1993 (as Something), 1994-present (as Anything)
How can I do this?
I have tried to use split like this:
 String s = previousString.split("\\$")[0] +  ")";
but it cut the last part of the String, so the result looks like this:
1984 (as Word), 1984-1993 (as Something)

Is the $ guaranteed to be followed by an unsigned number always? What will you want to happen if it isn’t? Also, is it required to occur within brackets and just before the right bracket, )?

You could use string.replaceAll which accepts a regex to remove a $ followed by one or more digits:
String input = "1984 (as Word$55), 1984-1993 (as Something$74435), 1994-present (as Anything$9324879)";
input = input.replaceAll("\\$\\d+", "");

System.out.println(input);


You can use the following Java regex expression to remove the $ symbol and numbers that follow it:
  String input = "1984 (as Word$55), 1984-1993 (as Something$74435), 1994-present (as Anything$9324879)";
  String output = input.replaceAll("\\$\\d+", "");

\\$ Escapes the $ symbol (which has special meaning in regex)
\\d+ Matches one or more digits.
You can learn about Regex here

Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.
